# Why does my string permutation algorithm only work with 3 or less letters?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, permutation

The Code:

```
function recursiveParse(letters, index) {
    var i,
        index = index || 0;
        stringOfLetters = '';

    while(index < letters.length) {
        stringOfLetters += letters[index] + recursiveParse(letters, ++index);
    }
    return stringOfLetters;
}

function calcPermutations(letters, index, permutations) {
    var head,
        index = index || 0,
        i,
        swapLetters,
        permutation,
        permutations = permutations || {};

    swapLetters = function(letters, index1, index2) {
        var tmp = letters[index2];

        letters[index2] = letters[index1];
        letters[index1] = tmp;

        return letters;
    }
    if(index < letters.length) {
        head = letters.splice(index, 1).join('');

        for(i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
            permutation = head + swapLetters(letters.slice(0), index, i).join('');
            permutations[permutation] = true;
        }
        letters.splice(index, 0, head);
        calcPermutations(letters, ++index, permutations); 
    }
    return permutations;
}

function testPermutations() {
    var expectedPermutations = ['atr', 'rat', 'rta', 'tar', 'tra', 'art'],
        actualPermutations = calcPermutations(['a', 'r', 't']);

    for(var i = 0; i < expectedPermutations.length - 1; i++) {
        if(actualPermutations[expectedPermutations[i]] !== true) {
            console.log("You're missing " + expectedPermutations[i]);
        } else {
            console.log("You've got " + expectedPermutations[i]);
        }
    }
    return actualPermutations;
}
testPermutations();
```

When I run `testPermutations` and pass in a 3 letter word, it works fine. However, when I try four, a bunch of permutations are coming up missing. What's the flaw in my logic?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vQ6qg

Comment: @Paul, I'm having a hard time seeing what you changed (if anything).

Comment: He didn't provide a fiddle, so I did.  I only added console.log output for the four letter case, so I can see what it does.

Comment: Are you aware that swapLetters() permanently alters the input letters array as a side effect? Javascript arrays are always more or less passed-by-reference into a function.

Comment: @Paul, yeah I'm aware. that's why I do an array.slice(0). this basically clones the array.

Comment: Didn't see that the first time through...  Well, I'm possibly just making things worse by adding more cloning.  I agree the 4 letter case is wrong.

Comment: The return from the recursive call to calcPermutations is discarded. Is that intentional?

Comment: I did not look deep in your implementation, however it seems that for a string length `n`, you are executing `n * (n-1)` iterations, while it should be `n!`. You are missing an inner for loop, or you should recursively call you calcPermutations for lengths > 3

Comment: Here's one that works by aggregating the results of recursions: http://jsfiddle.net/jUh7X/2/